# Matchstick Puzzle 4971

Tags: visual, matches

[image]

Rewriting the puzzle in text:

Move exactly 2 matchsticks to make this equality true:

4 + 9 - 7 = 1

Important Points:

- By the word 'move', I would also like to allow the possibility of 'remove', to allow for additional creative solutions.
- You can use both operations, move and remove, in your solution, but the total number of matchsticks which you move or remove should be 2 only.
- That is, you can do one of the following alternatives:

  - 2 move operations
  - 2 remove operations
  - 1 move and 1 remove operation (in any order)
- The equality must not be converted into inequalities. Please don't modify the equality symbol.
- Please do not introduce more matchsticks into the puzzle.
- I don't have a full list of solutions.

Comment: Where did you find the image?

Comment: I clicked a picture at home.

Comment: Although the question has been marked as closed, Viewers are encouraged to think of more solutions. Happy Puzzling!

Comment: That is the reason it was closed - there appear to be an unlimited number of solutions, which is not how puzzles here are supposed to work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OP explicitly forbids tinkering with the given equals sign, but

> nothing is said about adding a second one.

Therefore, moving two:

> -4 + 5 = 1 = 1

Similarly, removing one and moving (or rather just very slightly nudging) one:

> -1 + 9 - 7 = 1

And a third one (move two):

> 11 + 3 - 7 = 7

Comment: Haha, that's pretty clever :D

Answer (score 12):

By removing matchsticks:

> Pick up the horizontal matchsticks at the top and bottom of the 9, leaving 4+4-7=1.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution, by moving two times.

> [image]

Comment: Note that this also works the other way round (i.e. you can swap the first two numbers).

Answer (score 4):

> 1 + 9 - 9 = 1 (move two left-most from 4 to make 1, add two to 7 to make 9)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that moves two matchsticks:

> -4 + 6 - 1 = 1 (Convert the 9 to 6, and use the top of the 7 to make a negative sign)

Answer (score 2):

> 9 - 9 + 1 = 1 (move the vertical matchstick from `+` onto `4` to make a `9` and then move top horizontal matchstick from 7 to change the second `-` into a `+`)